# VUE 3 - use fetched data in other method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vuejs3

Hello I'm trying to use fetched data in other method in VUE 3. I just want to load all data on app start and then use them multiple times in code. My code is:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
 data() {
  return {
   dataAll : [],
  };
 },

 mounted() {
  this.getData();
  this.otherFunction();
 },

 methods: {
  getData() {
   fetch('app/api.php')
   .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.dataAll = data;
      //this.dataAll = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  },
  otherFunction() {
   console.log(this.dataAll);
  }
});
```

But the console shows `Proxy {} - Array(0)`. Where do I make a mistake?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fetch function is asynchronous and you are not waiting for the getData function to resolve before calling otherFunction.

Wait for the promise to resolve before calling other functions that depends on the data:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      dataAll: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData().then(() => {
      this.otherFunction();
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      return fetch('app/api.php')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.dataAll = data;
        });
    },
    otherFunction() {
      console.log(this.dataAll);
    }
  }
});
```

Or you can also use async await

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      dataAll: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getData();
    this.otherFunction();
  },
  methods: {
    async getData() {
      const data = await fetch(
        "app/api.php"
      ).then((response) => response.json());
      this.dataAll = data;
    },
    otherFunction() {
      console.log(this.dataAll);
    }
  }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#using_the_fetch_api

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await

Comment: await conversion is incomplete, there's still `then`. otherFunction is not chained, which is needed at least for error handling